# 'Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.' error with two lines in a unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue with this error that keeps on appearing with the lines that mention : `spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();` and `selectable = GetComponent<Selectable>();`

The error message that is displayed from my unity engine is

> 'Invalid token '='  in class, struct, or interface member declaration.'

The problem seems to be around the equal symbols in these lines and I don't understand what the issue is with it. Could I possibly get any advice on this please?

```
void Start()
{
    List<string> deck = Solitaire.GenerateDeck();
    solitaire = FindObjectOfType<Solitaire>();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (string card in deck)
    {
        cardFace = solitaire.cardFaces[i];
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
selectable = GetComponent<Selectable>();

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (selectable.faceUp == true)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = cardFace;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = cardBack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using break; within your foreach? also your i++; must be within the foreach so that it can work, the value of i is 0 constantly through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating two objects which will be used in your class'es methods. You need to create a field for that in your class (C# is a strongly typed language, and you need to explain the compiler what you're trying to achieve). In case of local variables you can use the `var` keyword, but for the fields you need to declare the full type, like this:

```
private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
private Selectable _selectable = GetComponent<Selectable>();
```

However, better solution will be to move this inside your function `Update`:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    var selectable = GetComponent<Selectable>();

    if (selectable.faceUp == true)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = cardFace;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = cardBack;
    }
}
```

Also you remove comparing with `true`:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    var selectable = GetComponent<Selectable>();

    if (selectable.faceUp)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = cardFace;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = cardBack;
    }
}
```

Or, using ternary operator

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    var selectable = GetComponent<Selectable>();
    spriteRenderer.sprite = selectable.faceUp ? cardFace : cardBack;
}
```